# Cannot create a XPath with iFrame as root element

Tags: selenium, xpath, iframe

I'm trying to create an XPath locator for an element that is inside an iFrame:
I want this iframe to be the root of XPath because I have two similar elements in 2 different iframes - but seem unable to do so
any ideas why it's not working?

edit- I'm not trying to interact with this element in any way(I know that I need to switch frames before interacting with elements inside it I'm just having an XPath locator problem) I want to create an XPath with iframe as the root element because of the situation mentioned above
here's the code:

```
<div id="framesWrapper">
    <div id="frame1Wrapper">
        <iframe src="/sample" id="frame1" width="500px" height="350px"></iframe>
            #document
                <DOCTYPE hmtl>
                <html>
                    <head>...</head>
                    <body style="background-color:#a9a9a9" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1065.0" data-gr-ext-installed=""><h1 id="sampleHeading">This is a sample page</h1>
                        <h1 id="sampleHeading">This is a sample page</h1>
                    </body>

                </html>

    </div>
    <div id="frame2Wrapper" class="mt-4">
        <iframe src="/sample" id="frame2" width="100px" height="100px"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: each frame will have a different handle and DOM structure.  You need to switch the driver to the frame before finding anything in it.  Use a webdriverwait with expectedcondition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(int)  Then find the elements inside.

Comment: If I was you, I will edit this question and _copy-and-paste_ the portion of the DOM that you took a screen shot of, enclosed in ```.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you need to wait for the page to load before attempting to interact with elements on the page (seems like common sense). However, what you may not know is that

1. If you don't use implicit or explicit wait, the web driver will attempt to interact with web elements immediately. On slow-loading pages, this will result in an error because the web element(s) in question will not be available.
2. Using an implicit wait (using the `WebDriver` object) only waits until a predetermined timeout elapses. This tend to be a bit slow because it won't break out of the wait if the page loads fast.
3. Using an explicit wait (using `WebDriverWait` class) allows you to set a condition that will tell the web driver to break out of the wait if the condition is met (i.e. a web element is visible on the page).

If you knew these facts, forgive me for going into this explanation. I thought it was necessary for what it is to follow.

The general recipe for interacting with a web element located in an iframe is as follows:

#### 1) Locate the iframe first

```
WebDriver driver... // your web driver instance
Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(10); // adjust to your needs
Duration sleepBetweenPolls = Duration.ofMillis(10); // default "sleep" is 500 milliseconds
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, sleepBetweenPolls); // wait object can be reused
...
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath(...))); // passing the XPath of the iframe
```

I explicitly created all the objects you need so that you can see or understand better their function. For example, you don't need to explicitly create the `Duration` objects. I just thought it was more helpful to show it this way. Also, since you don't need the iframe web element, there is no variable declaration preceding the `wait.until(...)`. All you need is  create a wait condition for the iframe to be available before you attempt step #2 below.

#### 2) Locate the Web Element

```
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(...))); // pass the xpath of the element
button.click(); // you might need something other than a button. There are other conditions to wait for (i.e. visibility of elements, availability of elements, etc.)
```

#### 3) Return to the main (parent) frame when you are done

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

That should be pretty much what you need. Obviously, there is more to this. `TimeoutException` is the exception that is thrown if the timeout limit is reached. You may or may not want to wrap those lines of code in a try/catch. Typically what I do is I surround in a try/catch so that I can execute an alternate plan if my first attempt times out. For example, in some cases, I retry after an initial attempt. Other times, I attempt to locate another element. For instance, an element might be visible if no errors on the page loading occurs. So, my first attempt might be to locate that element and my second attempt might be to locate an expected error message. The point is that using a try/catch to handle timeouts might be beneficial.  One thing I forgot to mention is that `TimeoutException` is a type of `RuntimeException`. As such, you are not forced to catch (handle) them. It is up to you if you will simply let it fail, or handle in a more graceful way.

Obviously in your case, you have two iframes you need to deal with. All you need to do is follow this recipe for both, explicitly passing the correct locator for each AND switching to the parent frame when you are done. This is very important. Otherwise, when you attempt to interact with other components in the parent frame, your web driver won't be able to because it will still thinks it is attempting to locate those components in the last frame you told it to look in (and that won't exist anymore).

Comment: this is not my problem - I apologize maybe my description was not clear enough -steps you mentioned are steps we take after creating a locator for an element -- to interact with it -- I want to create a locator with the abovementioned criteria -- iframe being the root of the XPath selector just like we would with let's say for element <div>     <p>...</p>    </div> -- selector would be //div//p

Comment: @GiorgiBazierashvili it doesn't work that way I'm afraid. You have to explicitly use distinct locators; one for the iframe and one for the component. When a component is in an iframe, the way the spec for web drivers work is that a separate document (DOM) is returned for the iframe. You have to locate it first to return the new document, then you have to locate the component inside of it. Even if this locator you are referring to works from the browser's dev tools, it will not work within the execution of a web driver for the reason I mentioned. Trust me when I say this is the answer you need.

Comment: @GiorgiBazierashvili this is the reason why relative XPaths won't work from the parent frame. You have to switch to the iframe first. For that, you need to locate the iframe, switch to it, then all the elements inside that document (DOM) will be visible to the web driver. Your description was clear. The solution you think you need is not possible. What I described here is the only way to accomplish it. You can go over the specification if you need further clarification. I assure you, my answer is correct.